# Ansible Molecule how to use multiple group_vars

Tags: ansible, molecule

I have a folder structure like this in Ansible where global variables are at the root group_vars and then environment specific variables are in inventories/dev/group_vars/all etc.

```
.
├── ansible.cfg
├── group_vars
│   └── all
├── inventories
│   ├── dev
│   │   ├── group_vars
│   │   │   └── all
│   │   └── hosts
│   └── prod
│       ├── group_vars
│       │   └── all
│       └── hosts
└── playbook.yml
```

I want to use to be able reuse the existing variables in both var files in Molecule but unable to do so as it cannot find the variable. Something similar to the below works but I need both group_vars/all and inventories/dev/group_vars/all

extract of my molecule.yml

```
provisioner:
  name: ansible
  inventory:
    links:
      group_vars: ../../../group_vars
```

I tried comma separated and that doesn't work because afterall it's just a symlink to the file.